# Ubuntu Studio LVM password entry box missing

Tags: password, encryption, plymouth, ubuntu-studio

I've just installed Ubuntu Studio 20.04. I configured it to create an encrypted LVM.
When I start up (I have "quiet splash" in my `/etc/default/grub`) the splash screen pops up and asks me for the LUKS password. But the place to enter the password is invisible. You can still type it in, and it echos little dots as you type, but the first time I booted it up I sat waiting for the test entry box to appear. It never did.

This is really cosmetic rather than functional, but how can I get the text entry box to appear? It would be nice to realise that it's waiting for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I developed that plymouth theme (it's forked from Xubuntu) and the original author had no box for LUKS encryption. I use LUKS encryption myself, but never needed more than the actual text to prompt me.

FYI, this theme is likely to be replaced in future versions of Ubuntu Studio. I'll probably backport the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the clarification. You are correct in that it's not really necessary (I did mention that it's cosmetic rather than functional), but it caught me by surprise the first time! I'm happy to wait for the new version and/or backports!